# How to add a background image to a font awesome icon?

Tags: html, css, icons, background-image, font-awesome

I want to make the coloring of the icon an image. So instead of it being purple or something, it is the image. I hope that makes sense!

I have this code:

```
<span class="fa fa-coffee fa-5x coffee" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

and the class:

```
.coffee {
background: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/xal8sws9h4qy06l/tumblr_n6hoofK5GW1r0hv8uo1_500.gif?dl=1");
}
```

but this just changes the area around the icon to that image, not the inside.

Here's the whole page, the icon I'm trying to modify is the coffee cup: http://codepen.io/l-emi/pen/QNZevb

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome Background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516353/font-awesome-background-color)

Comment: you could create image masks but this will only work when the background is a solid color, if you're ok with that I can write an answer.

Comment: @Aziz yep go ahead

Answer (score 4):

You could use `background-clip` and `text-fill-color` to achieve this in webkit browsers though it won't work in other browsers unfortunately:

```
.coffee:before {
  background: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/xal8sws9h4qy06l/tumblr_n6hoofK5GW1r0hv8uo1_500.gif?dl=1");
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

[EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaVKKx)

Comment: Hmm, is there any other way I can do this then which would work in other browsers? Maybe through something other than font awesome

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Turnip there is -webkit filter for that. However it is more convenient to use SVG:

```
<svg>
  <pattern id="mypattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="750" height="800">
    <image width="750" height="800" xlink:href="https://placekitten.com/g/100/100"></image>
  </pattern>
  <text x="0" y="80" class="fa fa-5x"
      style="fill:url(#mypattern);">&#xf0f4;</text>
</svg>
```

You just need to include icon character in SVG

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xd6gny56/)

Comment: Thanks, this is great! It only works with still images though, right?

Comment: I believe it doesn't matter if its still image or gif: https://jsfiddle.net/xd6gny56/1/

Comment: I was just writing a demo similar to this but using an SVG path. +1 for using a text element. Very good

Answer (score 1):

You may also take a look at mix-blend-mode . http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/eZQdEg (or snippet at the bottom of answser)

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Modification to your CSS :

```
.coffee {
  position:relative;/* to bring it on top */
  mix-blend-mode:screen;/* we will blend from black and white colors */
  color:black;/* this color will blend */
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100px white; /* this will be the mask color */
}
.infobox {/* #infobox should be used only once, so i use a class */
  position:relative;/* to position the child */
}
.infobox:before{/* child or pseudo */
  content:'';
  /* slide it under the .coffebox */
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-70px;
  height:140px;
  width:140px;
  position:absolute;
  /* image to blend with */ 
  background: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/czz3m5ieucxwbrl/stars.gif?dl=1");
}
```

modification to your html *(where you use unproperly the ID too many times)*:

```
<div class="col-md-4 infobox " id="infobox" style="font-size: 28px;">
  <span class="fa fa-coffee fa-5x coffee" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

```css
.coffee {
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100px white;
}
.infobox {
  position: relative;
}
.infobox:before {
  content: '';
  height: 140px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/czz3m5ieucxwbrl/stars.gif?dl=1"),
  /* see gradient  while image loads*/
  linear-gradient(45deg, darkblue, white, darkblue, white, darkblue, white, darkblue, white);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4 infobox " id="infobox" style="font-size: 28px;">
  <span class="fa fa-coffee fa-5x coffee" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your background is a solid color you could use an inverted SVG icon (where the filled path is the white-space and the main icons are cut/transparent):

[image: inverted SVG icon]

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #ede1e9;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.maskicon {
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://i.giphy.com/l2QZVskdU1QXM3I1a.gif') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.maskicon svg {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.maskicon svg path { fill: #ede1e9; }

.maskicon.coffee svg { height: 45vh; }
```

```html
<div class="maskicon coffee">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="782 -846 1856 1792"><path d="M2254-398h-64v384h64c53.3 0 98.7-18.7 136-56s56-82.7 56-136-18.7-98.7-56-136-82.7-56-136-56z"/><path d="M782-846V562h1792c0 70.7-25 131-75 181s-110.3 75-181 75H1038c-70.7 0-131-25-181-75s-75-110.3-75-181v384h1870.9V-846H782zM2525.5 65.5c-75 75-165.5 112.5-271.5 112.5h-64v32c0 61.3-22 114-66 158s-96.7 66-158 66h-704c-61.3 0-114-22-158-66s-66-96.7-66-158v-736c0-17.3 6.3-32.3 19-45 12.7-12.7 27.7-19 45-19h1152c106 0 196.5 37.5 271.5 112.5S2638-312 2638-206 2600.5-9.5 2525.5 65.5z"/></svg>
</div>
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/mp7fo9ah/

Having the `SVG` inside the `HTML` allows you to easily control its `fill` color to match the background. You could go further with this and have any `HTML` content as the background (like text or even video) if you make the `SVG` element absolutely positioned with a higher `z-index`.

This requires more maintenance but is compatible with most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In [**your Codepen demo**](http://codepen.io/l-emi/pen/QNZevb), just replace...

```
.coffee:before {
    background: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/czz3m5ieucxwbrl/stars.gif?dl=1");
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

... with...

```
.coffee:before {
    background: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/xal8sws9h4qy06l/tumblr_n6hoofK5GW1r0hv8uo1_500.gif?dl=1");
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Then, `https://www.dropbox.com/s/xal8sws9h4qy06l/tumblr_n6hoofK5GW1r0hv8uo1_500.gif?dl=1` will be the background image of your icon.

The problem with the code in your question, is that you were using selector `.coffee` where you should have been using selector `.coffee:before`.

---

#### Edit :

If you want to use the same background for the wand (as mentioned in the comments below), you could use eg. this selector :

```
.coffee:before, .fa-magic:before {
    background: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/eg3v313y3fuha9b/ezgif.com-crop.gif?dl=1");
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but say I want to apply the same background to another icon (i.e the wand at the top). Do I use ".wand:before"? I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: @l-emi yes, if you want unique backgrounds, otherwise you could just apply the same `::before` pseudo element to all the icons you want with a more general selector.

Comment: @l-emi : If you want it to work on the wand as well, you could use eg. selector `.coffee:before, .fa-magic:before`.

Answer (score 0):

add a search icon using FontAwesome icon. searchbox is the div or any tag class name.

```
.searchbox:before {
  position:absolute;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  top: 17px;
  left: 20px;
  content: "\f002";
}
```