# Icon resolution with his block (Font Awsome)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I used Font Awesome for the icon and in the hover it is what I like this results[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3fIW.png)

and also I have this problem when a link is selected that is what I have [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmSgR.png)

I use bootstrap

```css
.nav > li > a:hover
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
.iconetwitter
{
    color: #ffffff;
    width: auto;
    height: 33px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: background-color color 0.2s, font-size 0.2s , ease-in-out;
}
.iconetwitter:hover , .iconetwitter:focus ,.iconetwitter:active
{
    color: #1DA1F2;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
                    <li class="contacteicone col-md-3">
                        <a href="#" class="monicone">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter-square iconetwitter fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your code?

Comment: @JoostS I don't know how ?

Comment: Is your website online? Then send a link. Is it not online? Then send a codepen, where you paste the html, css and js: http://codepen.io

Comment: @JoostS thanks a lot for showing me this website ! that's it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grRGBN

Comment: @JoostS I use bootstrap and font awsome too !

Comment: Your website has thousands of lines of code (multiple css files and icon frameworks) and you are sharing only a small portion through codepen. Please put your website online somewhere so we can see the whole thing and see what you see. Sorry... but that is the only way.

Comment: @AblaMohamedAmine No codepin! Use JSFiddle.

Comment: @JoostS that's it https://www.sendspace.com/file/3t8ti0

Answer (score 1):

Got it...

The strange hover state is caused by the background color of your font-awesome icons. The background is larger than the character. Correct this with line-height, like this:

```
.fa {line-height: 0.85em;}
```

Or use the nicer solution is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27382026/2397550. Then you should use this icon for the underlying square: http://fontawesome.io/icon/square/

The white area behind a focussed icon is because you did this:

```
.nav > li > a:hover {background-color: transparent;}
```

This should be:

```
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {background-color: transparent;}
```