# Change color of font-awesome star icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

I have a font-awesome star-o icon and onclick I want to set its color to yellow. Can some one help me?

`<div id="favourite_star">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg left">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-star-o fa-stack-1x favourite_icon" onclick="setLocally()"></i></span>
</div>`

I just want the color inside the star to be set yellow. I tried to set it using jquery the color to yellow but it sets only the edges of star to yellow and then I tried with the background-color to yellow then its sets the whole square to yellow.

Comment: `$("#favourite_star .fa-star-o").css({"color":"yellow"});`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516353/font-awesome-background-color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change the star class in [`.star`](http://fontawesome.io/icon/star/) instead of [`.star-o`](http://fontawesome.io/icon/star-o/)

So

```
// HTML
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-star-o fa-stack-1x favourite_icon"></i>

// JS
$(".favourite_icon").click(function(){
 $(this).css({"color": "yellow"}).removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
});
```

Comment: thanks worked perfectly :) I was not doing the remove class.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>



<i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size:48px;color:yellow"></i>
<br>



</body>
</html>
```

**Or try this**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>fa fa-star</h1>

<i class="fa fa-star"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size:24px"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size:36px"></i>
<i class="fa fa-star" style="font-size:48px;color:yellow"></i>
<br>

<p>Used on a button:</p>
<button style="font-size:24px">Button <i class="fa fa-star"></i></button>

<p>Unicode:</p>
<i style="font-size:24px" class="fa">&#xf005;</i>

</body>
</html>
```